# httpd 2.4 ProxyPassMatch merge multiple slashes in regex

Tags: regex, apache, php, fastcgi

The current code I am using is

`^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/puphpet/puphpet.com/web/$1`

This works for proper URLs, ex `http://puphpet.dev/app_dev.php/github-btn`

If the URL has multiple slashes it's passing both slashes along, `http://puphpet.dev/app_dev.php//github-btn`

The multiple slashes are breaking my sites. I am aware that nginx has something that merges multiple slashes together, but have been unable to find something similar with httpd. I have tried multiple regexes for the match but they don't seem to be working as I'd expect.

For example, `(.*\.php)(/)(.*)` matches the above URL as

`$1` /app_dev.php
`$2` /
`$3` /github-btn

So I would think passing `$1$3` to the proxy would work, but alas it does not.

---

### edit

After quite a bit of dancing around ProxyPassMatch's regex, I ended up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
ProxyPassMatch /(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/puphpet/puphpet.com/web/$1
```

Which fixes the double slash in the URL by redirecting to a single URL. However, a completely new request isn't the most optimal solution, in my opinion. Transparently rewriting the URL for all further matches below it would be best.

Comment: How do these URLs with multiple consecutive slashes get requested in the first place? If your app does not output false links this should not even happen. (And normal visitors seldom mess with URLs that way – and if they did, their problem.)

Comment: @CBroe it's "bad" code that's created the URLs using Symfony2/Twig path() feature. I'm guessing I created them incorrectly, but I can't get over how something so trivial could break my apps.